# Ссылки в таблице (html, css)

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, хотел вывести в браузере таблицу со ссылками на файли.
Три ячейки. При наведении на них они должен меняться фон ячейки, но этого не происходит. Может я что-то не так делаю?

Есть файл index.html:

```
<html>
<head> 
<title>Пример</title>
<link href="css/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style>
 table {
   border: 1px solid black;
   background: stateblue2;
 }
 tr {
   border: 1px solid black;
 }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <table>
 <tr><td> 
     <a href="index.html">Главная</a>
 </td></tr> 
 <tr><td> 
     <a href="hobby.html">Мое хобби</a>
 </td></tr> 
 <tr><td>
     <a href="photo.html">Фотоальбом</a>
 </td></tr>  
 </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

есть файли index.html, hobby.html, photo.html. Также есть файл style.css:

```
td {display: block; background-color: stateblue2; height:50px; width:100px; border:1px solid black; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle"; text-decoration: none;}
td:hover {color: black; background-color:  royalblue2;}
```

Comment: a : hover нужно писать без пробелов a:hover

Comment: @DmitriyKondratiuk, не помагает. ячейки белые, и нету границ нижних

Comment: royalblue2 цвета лучше писать в таком  #436EEE или таком rgb( 67, 110, 238) формате

Comment: скажите, пожалуйста почему так?

Comment: не знаю, как Вы это сделали, но могу попросить Вас дать ссылку или лучше сделать код, который я напишу Вам (так само, как Вы скинули мне свой вариант, то есть,чтобы работало), пожалуйста

Comment: В чем может быть причина, если не то,чтобы цвет, а и подчеркивание ссылки не убирается и нету выравнивания ее по центру

Comment: и, если Вас не затруднит, скинете его в той формочке, что и предидущий  кидали)

Comment: Подправил свой ответ.

Comment: в стиле в вопросе лишняя кавычка затеслась

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо, но к сожалению, єто не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ на вопрос. Все дело было в неправильном цвете, вернее названия были неправильными. Видимо сайт, с которого я их брал - содержит неверные данные.

```
<html>
<head> 
<title>Пример</title>
<link href="css/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style>
 table {
 border: 2px solid black;
 background: #87CEEB;
 }
 td {
 border: 2px solid black;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <table class="valign">
 <tr><td> 
 <a href="index.html">Главная</a>
 </td></tr> 
 <tr><td> 
 <a href="hobby.html">Мое хобби</a>
 </td></tr> 
 <tr><td>
 <a href="photo.html">Фотоальбом</a>
 </td></tr>  
 </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/74x067m1/
Пожалуйста

```
<html>
<head> 
 <title>Приклад</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <table>
 <tr><td> 
   <a href="#">Привет</a>
 </td></tr> 
 <tr><td> 
  <a href="#">Привет</a>
 </td></tr> 
 <tr><td>
   <a href="#">Привет</a>
 </td></tr>  
 </table>
 </body>
 </html>


a {display:block;
color: red; background-color: blue;

height:50px;
width:50px;}
a:hover {color: black; background-color: green;}
```

Comment: и все же таблица не строиться

Comment: есть просто ссылки

Comment: ячейки без рамок

Comment: Вы же про цвет говорили?Рамки ставятся border, таблица есть, ТР это строка их 3 и по 1 столбцу

Comment: не совсем правильно выразился

Comment: меняет цвет ячейка

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/1ga90tL9/

```
table{
  border: 1px solid black
}
 td{
    border: 1px solid black
  }
```

Comment: не выделяет все равно

Comment: давайте я напишу, что я делаю

Comment: я только начал разбираться, возможно что-то неправильно выполняю, так что простите мое невежество, если что)

Answer (score 0):

```css
td {display: block; background-color: red; height:50px; width:130px; border:1px solid black; display:table-cell; vertical-aling: middle; text-align:center;}
td:hover {color: black; background-color:  #436EEE;}
td a { text-decoration: none; display:inline-block; color: #000000;}
```

```html
<html>
<head> 
<title>Пример</title>
<link href="css/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style>
 table {
   border: 1px solid black;
   background: stateblue2;
 }
 tr {
   border: 1px solid black;
 }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <table>
 <tr><td> 
    <a href="index.html">Главная</a>
 </td></tr> 
 <tr><td> 
    <a href="hobby.html">Мое хобби</a>
 </td></tr> 
 <tr><td>
    <a href="photo.html">Фотоальбом</a>
 </td></tr>  
 </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: даже после Вашей корректировки ничего не происходит. и чтобы я не писал ничего не работает